# Как составить регулярное выражение, понимающее разницу между словом и словосочетанием с этим словом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-basic

Использую `System.Text.RegularExpressions`
Есть два типа документов: Счет и Счет фактура

Нужно однозначно сказать, что это разные строки.
Условие, что Счет может иметь значения:

> Счет, Сч, Счт

а Счет фактура значения:

> СФ, СЧФ, СЧФК и т.д.

Который день бьюсь не могу понять как это сделать.
Нужен паттерн. Для `СФ` сделал такой: `с[^\s]*ф[^\s]*`

Answer (score 0):

В целом, я бы писал явно

```
^\s*Счет|Сч|Счт\s*$
```

и

```
^\s*СФ|СЧФ|СЧФК\s*$
```

а дальше, через пайп (палочку) добавлять по мере надобности.

**UPD**

Максимум улучшения, который я сейчас вижу - это привести все к одному регистру. А если пришло что то неведомое - спросить у автора опуса и забить в базу/конфиг. Но нужно учитывать, что разные люди могут использовать пересекающиеся слова.

Но если хочется пойти дальше, то может быть есть смысл посмотреть на [Soundex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Comment: Я тоже начинаю к этому приходить, но вариантов оказывается иногда очень много. Люди пишут так как им на душу ляжет. Поэтому сначала хотелось бы попробовать отделить мух от котлет при помощи РВ